# RealmList inside RealmObject not being populated from json

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

so I started playing around with Realm and its been pretty self-explanatory for my simple use cases so far but I've found that creating a realm object with a realmList inside it from Json doesn't populate the realm list. Here's what I've got:

```
public class User extends RealmObject{

    @PrimaryKey
    private int user_id;

    private RealmList<Place> places;

    private String fname;

    private String lname;

    private String birth_date;

    public RealmList<Place> getPlaces(){
        return this.places;
    }

    public void setPlaces(RealmList<Place>places) {
        this.places = places;
    }
}


public class Place extends RealmObject{

    private String place_name;
    //several other types all ints and Strings with getters and setters

}
```

both of these classes have appropriate getters and setters in my actual code I simply included a sample of information and all of the important info to shorten this.

I am using retrofit and all of the data is coming in as jsonelements.

```
userService.requestProfile(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void success(JsonElement profileResponse, Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, profileResponse.toString()); //shows raw response containing multiple places objects
            realm.beginTransaction();

            User user  = null;
            try {
                user = (User)realm.createObjectFromJson(User.class, profileResponse.toString());
            }catch (RealmException re){
                re.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(user != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, user.getFname()); //comes out correctly
                Log.d(TAG, user.getPlaces().size()) //always says 0
            }
            realm.commitTransaction();


        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            error.getCause();
        }
    });
```

Any idea why I'm not seeing anything when I call getPlaces on user? I have tried embedding realm objects in realm objects and it seems fine, only realmList seems to give me an issue. I'm not sure if the data is even being saved into realm in the first place when createObject is called. I also tried createAllFromJson but I get a

```
Could not create JSON array from string
```

exception
EDIT: Example json
    {"places":[{"place_id":1280,"place_name":"Canada"}}]}

Comment: Can you add your input JSON here? It seems the it is not an Array which you want to parse to Realm. It should be like `[{"name": "xxx"}]`

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Gson to deal with JSON. I have successfully used Gson, Retrofit and Realm with following implementation.

1. Build gson with exclusion strategy

   ```
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
               @Override
               public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                   return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
               }

               @Override
               public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                   return false;
               }
           })
   ```
2. Add Gson to RestAdapter builder

   ```
   RestAdapter.Builder()
           //.other settings
           .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
           .build();
   ```